# Prove that a construction exists: is this a constructive proof or existential proof?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-theory, constructive-mathematics

[This top answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397328/can-the-nonexistence-of-a-constructive-proof-be-proven-when-an-existential-proof) claims that it is possible to prove that a constructive proof cannot exist.

I think, if "non-existence of constructive proof" can be proven, then for some other questions, it is also possible to prove "the existence of constructive proof".

Consider the following statement: "existence of constructive proof without actually giving the construction algorithm."

I am very curious if this statement is considered a "constructive proof" or "existential proof".

Answer (score 7):

You have a formal system equipped with some notion of "constructive proof" (note that "constructive proof" is nigh-impossible to pin down with any kind of generality - there are only a few standard proof systems such as Peano Arithmetic where the distinction between constructive and non-constructive proofs is more-or-less agreed upon and understood, or systems such as Heyting Arithmetic or Martin-Löf Type Theory which only admit constructive proofs by design).

You start with a sentence (formula, proposition-as-type, etc.) $\psi$ of your chosen formal system, and consider a sentence (formula, etc.) $\varphi$ which denotes something like "*$\psi$ has a constructive proof (in the formal system under consideration)*". Then you ask:

> Would a non-constructive proof of $\varphi$ be considered a constructive or non-constructive proof of $\psi$?

By offering two alternatives, you unintentionally turned this into trick question! The short and correct answer is that a proof of $\varphi$ is **not considered** a proof of $\psi$ at all.

First, the easy formalities. Each formal proof has a conclusion, the sentence (formula, etc.) $\varphi$ that the proof actually establishes. This conclusion is unique: formally, a proof of $\varphi$ is a proof of $\varphi$, and not a proof of anything else. In particular, it's never a proof of some other formula, say $\psi$.

At this point, you might think that you can get around these formal issues by rephrasing your question slightly, via some tricky phrasing such as "can a proof of $\varphi$ always be turned into a proof of $\psi$ algorithmically..."

But Gödelian obstacles prevent you from doing that. The statements $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are not related in a sufficiently strong way. For example, $PA+\neg Con(PA)$ proves $\varphi$ (no matter what $\psi$ is), but (unless PA is inconsistent) it does not prove an arbitrarily chosen formula $\psi$, say $0 = 1$. Basically, a sufficiently strong formal system won't go from a proof of "there exists a proof of $\psi$" to a genuine proof of $\psi$ unless it believes itself consistent: but then, by the [second incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Second_incompleteness_theorem) the formal system was gravely mistaken about its own consistency anyway.

This answers your question: a non-constructive proof of "*$\psi$ has a constructive proof*" would not be considered a proof of $\psi$ at all, much less a constructive proof of $\psi$.

For further reading, assuming you already have a firm grasp of Gödel's theorems including Rosser's variant, you might want to read up on [arithmetical soundness](https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2009-May/013761.html) (if you can track down the first email of this FOM list discussion, it might be a good starting point; or see e.g. Boolos' The Logic of Provability), and the reflection theorem showing that [PA is not finitely axiomatizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3161687/how-to-prove-that-first-order-pa-proves-the-consistency-of-each-of-its-finite-su).

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer! In this specific case, I think, since $\varphi$ implies $\phi$, so a proof of $\varphi$ is a proof of $\phi$. Not sure my thinking is correct, though.

Comment: The implication $Provable( \lceil X \rceil ) \rightarrow X$ generally does not hold: see [Löb's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

It's constructive. Proofs are finite objects. If you know that a proof of $P$ exists, then you can find one, using the following method:

1. Generate every possible proof, starting with the shortest and working up by length
2. When you find a proof of $P$, stop

Note that this method only works if you already know that $P$ is provable.

Comment: Note that, even if we disregard metamathematical issues, this kind of unbounded search is usually *not* considered constructive. If the proof showing that "$P$ is provable" is not itself constructive (i.e. it does not give an upper bound on the length of the shortest proof of $P$), then you need to invoke [Markov's principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_principle) to show that your method for finding a proof terminates. But Markov's principle is not considered acceptable in most flavors of constructive mathematics.