# Proving a theorem by proving that there must be proof of it

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics

Is there an example where a mathematical theorem is proven by demonstrating the necessity of a proof, without actually providing the proof?

Comment: There is no such example. Even if you successfully prove "*$T$ has a proof*", a proof of "*$T$ has a proof*" does not count as a proof of $T$, for somewhat subtle logical reasons. I explained this e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4346276/645935) in the context of a closely related (albeit slightly different) question. (preemptive admin note: I won't turn this comment into an answer as it'd essentially be a dupe)

Comment: Regardless of whether this is considered evidence or not, is there any example at all that shows a particular case has evidence without providing the evidence?

Comment: I understand, you mean that the statement would be self-referential and therefore an invalid circular inference

Comment: @Z.A.K. You are correct; I misremembered the theorem, and my comment was completely erroneous.

Comment: @MarkSaving: No worries, glad we're on the same page.